# RTSP streaming in windows phone 8 application dont work with xaml media element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, rtsp, rtsp-client

I want to stream an RTSP live stream into windows phone 8 app from one of the IP camera.
I am using VS2012, mediaelemnt in xaml. it doesnt stream 
i am setting the source of media elemet as below. 
mediaelement.source="rtsp://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/media/video.sav"

There is no exception neither streaming.
please suggest me if there is any wrong or any alterate approach?

Comment: `MediaElement` doesn't support RTSP. You would need to implement an RTSP client that acts as a `MediaStreamSource`. This isn't simple and to my knowledge there isn't a public solution available.

Comment: is there any other sdk or control available so that i can buy and use?

Comment: I am ready to buy and use in my windows phone 8 project. If there are any SDKs are available please let me know.